# How to convert to list from many columns of dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql

I have this example dataframe:

```
id |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D 
1  |NULL | 1   | 1   |NULL
2  | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1
3  | 1   |NULL |NULL |NULL
```

and I want to change to this format:

```
id | newColumn
1  | {"B", "C"}
2  | {"A","B","C","D"}
3  | {"A"}
```

In other words, I want to make a new column with a list containing the column names where the row values are not null.

How can I do this in Spark using Scala?

Answer (score 0):

First, get the column names where there is an actual value and not null. This can be done with a function such as:

```
val notNullColNames = Seq("A", "B", "C", "D").map(c => when(col(c).isNotNull, c))
```

To create an array of values normally `array` is used, however, this will still give back a null when the input is null. Instead, one solution is to use `concat_ws` and `split` to remove any null values:

```
df.select($"id", split(concat_ws(",", notNullColNames:_*), ",").as("newColumn"))
```

For the example input, this will output:

```
+---+------------+
| id|   newColumn|
+---+------------+
|  1|      [B, C]|
|  2|[A, B, C, D]|
|  3|         [A]|
+---+------------+
```